# ¿Como puedo mover divs efectivamente con media queries?

Tags: html, div, responsive, mediaqueries

Eh estado intentando poner dos divs que siempre sean del mismo tamaño uno alado de otro por fila pero cuando sea mas chica la pantalla que se ponga uno debajo de otro. Debe haber una mejor forma pero no la puedo hacer efectivamente

Me estoy imaginando algo asi:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el codigo CSS que tengo:

```
 .modal_scroll {
    max-height: 500px;
    overflow-y: auto;
}

.modal_wrap{
    margin-top: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
}

.modal_square{
    padding-right: 5px;
    padding-left: 5px;
    height: 100%;
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.modal_img{
    margin-right: 5px;
    display: block;
    float: left;
}

.modal_description{
    display:block;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .modal_square { 
     border-top: 2px solid #cacaca;
     float: none;
     margin-right:0;
     width:auto; 
   }
 }

 @media screen and (max-height: 500px) {
    .modal_scroll {
        max-height: 300px;
        overflow-y: scroll;
    }
 }
```

Y esta es mi estructura en HTML:

```
    <div class="modal_scroll">
    <div class="cartTableHeader" colspan="4" style="background-color: #EBEDEF">
        <h4 class="margin-top-10" >Agregar Productos</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="modal_wrap">
        {% for publication_product in publication_products_to_add %}
        <div class="modal_square">
            <div class="modal_img">
                <a href="{% url "get_store_publication" publication_product.publication.id publication_product.publication.slug %}" target="_blank">
                <img src="{{ publication_product.images.0.url_115x115 }}" alt="{{ publication_product.name }}">
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="CartDescription col-xs-7 info_set">
                <h4>
                    <a href="{% url "get_store_publication" publication_product.publication.id publication_product.publication.slug %}" target="_blank">
                    {{ publication_product.name }}
                    </a>
                </h4>
                <span class="size">
                <span class="text_content_ss">Subtitle</span>
                <br>
                <span class="text_content_ss">Description</span>
                <br>
                <span class="text_content_ss">$00.00</span>
                <br>
                <span style="color:red;" class="text_content_ss">Alert: You need to add this</span>
                <br>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

revisa que tengas en el head el meta viewport, y podrias usar flexbox en tu codigo
espero haber sido de ayuda , saludos

```
`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">`
```

Answer (score 0):

Es mejor no usar `float`para estas cosas porque te va a romper el flujo del documento y luego tendras que restaurarlo entre otros problemas.
Mejor con flex, por ejemplo:

```css
.container {
display:flex;
width:100%;
}
.bloque{
flex:1;
margin:1%;
height:5em;
background:red;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
   .container { 
   flex-direction:column;
   }
 
 }
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="bloque"></div>
<div class="bloque"></div>
</div>
```

O con inline-block si no quieres usar flex. En este caso es mejor que no haya espacios en el codigo entre los dos div `.bloque` por una limitacion de inline-block que te impedira que esten "pegados", aunque si vas a dejar algo de margen entre ellos no hay problema:

```css
   .container {
width:100%;
   text-align:center;
}
.bloque{
width:49%;
margin:0 0.5%;
height:5em;
background:red;
  display:inline-block;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
   .bloque{
   width:100%;
   margin:1% 0;
   }
 }
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="bloque"></div><div class="bloque"></div>
</div>
```